# How to keep variables on disk instead of memory?

Tags: python, memory, disk

I am writing a python script that processes enormous amounts of data. The problem it that is uses more memory than my computer has, so I wanted to know if there is a way to store variables on a fast ssd, rather than memory.
The module I'm using to process the data is itertools, as I need to generate every possible combination for a specific string.

Comment: You can potentially use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). You can also split your data into chunks and process each bit separately.

Comment: You don't store "variables". Variables are just names that refer to *objects* in some namespace. You store *objects*. Yes, you can put objects on disk, but it won't act like an object in memory.

Comment: Would I still be able to access the objects even if it wouldn't be like it was in memory?

Comment: @Coolcreeper no, you'd have to deserialize them... back in to memory.

Comment: Look, there is probably no generic solution here, if you are trying to solve a *specific issue* you really need to give us more details